# CSS line-height pixel value not working

Tags: css

OK, so here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLJyV/
Each line of text should be 40px tall (`line-height: 40px`), but the `span` shows that that's not happening. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: dunno for me its working fine... seems like the span got some additonal margin /padding ... you should use btw xhtml.. looks cleaner and prevents mistakes. Morevoder see this: http://jsfiddle.net/YLJyV/1/  i gave that span a absolute positioning.. 40px line height looks pretty fine

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Setting line-height adds the extra space equally above and below each line, but in my example, the span extended above the line only. Setting `position:absolute` vertically aligns the span in the middle of the line.

Comment: @Abraham: you should post that as an answer to your question and then accept it tomorrow (you must wait 24 hours before you can accept an answer that you post to your own question) - I will upgrade the answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem is old and solved, but in case anyone else ends up here, today I learned that spans and divs handle line-height differently. More information: [why the span's line-height is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/YLJyV/28/

Is that what you are looking for?