# How do I make <p> and <span> have the same line-height in HTML 5?

Tags: css, html

How do I make `p` and `span` have the same line-height in HTML 5?

```
.main-body-text {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: robotolight, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/2yqvL7bg/10/)

Comment: What's your problem exactly ? Your JSFiddle shows that line-height is the same for P and SPAN

Comment: @Clément Malet: change the js fiddle to html 5 in the options

Comment: Perhaps the same question, perhaps not, but take a look at [why the span's line-height is useless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that `p` and `span` have different `display` types, resulting in different behaviors due to hidden spaces between lines.

If you want both of them to have the same `line-height`, force them to be of the same type :

```
display:inline; // or 'block' or 'inline-block'
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLg05L2d/)