# How to calculate the height of an inline element

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` element with the following CSS:

```
span.test {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Why the calculated height of the span seems to be 22px? Where do these 2 extra pixels come from?

[image]

Is it possible to make it tall 20px without using `inline-block` ?

Here is the simple jsbin I used to test: http://jsbin.com/tigevecemoco/1/edit

Comment: does line height do anything in your code?

Comment: `line-height: 1` seems to act like `line-height: 100%`, both setting the line-height to 20px (font-size). I can't tell where the extra pixels come from, but I do see them. Testing in Chrome.

Comment: if you use line height it should have pixels as far as I know. so I'd make it 20px. I don't know where the extra pixels come from, but if you need the font to be 20px and it can't be 18px, I think it will stay 22px high

Comment: After some research I think it's not possible to do this without `inline-block`

Comment: I would like to see an answer to this as well.  It seems to depend on the font.  But what font metric exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The CSS 2.1 spec says:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)

> **10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements**
>
> The 'height' property does not apply. The height of the content area should be based on the font, but this specification does not specify how.

As it happens the height, as opposed to the line-height, of a non-replaced inline element has very little effect on anything else so browsers are pretty free to report whatever number they like here.

However, a little reverse engineering can be instructive.

If we look at the font metrics for Times New Roman, we see EM size of 2048, WinAscent of 1825, and WinDescent of 443. Sum the ascent and descent, divide by the EM size, multiply by the font size (20px) and round to the integer and we get 22px.

Taking Arial as another font, we have EM size of 2048, WinAscent of 1854, and WinDescent of 434. Do the calculation again and we again get 22px.

What about a different font? Tahoma has EM size of 2048, WinAscent of 2049, and WinDescent of 423. Do the calculation again and this time we get 24px. And hey presto, if you try your JsBin with the Tahoma font, Firefox does indeed show a height of 24px.

The font metrics above were obtained from loading the fonts into [Type Light 3.2](http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html).

Not conclusive, but a reasonable suggestion of how it all works.

> Is it possible to make it tall 20px without using inline-block ?

Assuming the above is correct, you should be able to achieve it by using a custom font and modifying the font metrics of that font to suit. I wouldn't like to predict the knock-on effects of doing that though.

Comment: Also see [section 10.8.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height), which discusses how the height of a line box is (or may be) calculated with respect to line-height, although note that it references section 10.6.1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an answer to why it is applied. I found many forums with the same question...

But, as an answer to your request:

**Is it possible to make it tall 20px without using inline-block ?**

I managed to do it only by floating the element. It seems to lose whatever it was that was padding it... Then, setting the `line-height` to specific `20px` makes it work.

```css
span.test {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">A</span>
```

**EDIT**

Actually, adding `float` works because it makes `inline` elements behave like `block` elements.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

[image: try use "line-height"]

'**line-hieght:1**' is inherited from parent. try own line-height.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. If I set `line-height: 20px` it is still `22px` tall. Could you link me your jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

[MDN line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

[why the span's line-height is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless)

Hope this helps.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I used JS Bin http://jsbin.com/siqabekoloja/1/edit to solve your issue. I was able to get it consistent in IE, Chrome and Firefox. I believe the problem is you need the element to be block  not an inline element .

Hope this helps. If you want them to be next to each other just float them left or right.