# Why baseline of `inline-block` element with `overflow:hidden` is set to its bottom margin?

Tags: html, css, overflow, w3c

After reading two great answers explaining the behaviour of `inline-block` elements ([Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward) and [why the span's line-height is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless)) I still have two unexplained questions.

**1.** What the reason to change baseline of `inline-block` element from baseline of its line box to bottom margin edge?

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

**2.** How to calculate this shift?

[image]

**Important:** I don't try to find a solution how to *fix* it. I try to understand what was the reason to change positioning behaviour of `inline-block` element when it is applied `overflow: hidden`. So please, don't post answers for dummies.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately I didn't get what I want although I accepted the answer. I think the problem in the questions itself. Regarding **the first question**: I wanted to understand why `inline-block` can't preserve baseline of its line box even if it has `overflow:hidden` (despite of W3C specification of course). I wanted to hear the design decisions - not just it *must* be set to something, because W3C it mandates. **The second one**: I want to get a formula where we can paste `font-size` and `line-height` of an element and get the correct result.

Anyway thanks to anybody :)

**UPDATE 2**

Fortunately and subjectively the answer is found! See the first re-accepted answer. Thank you, @pallxk!)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to calculate the shift? You can make them line up using `vertical-align` on the `inline-block` elements if that's all you're after

Comment: I know that `vertical-align:top` fix this shift, but it's just interesting where the gap is come from.

Comment: I agree and find it even more interesting that any `vertical-align` setting seems to fix it in my tests so far.

Comment: On 1, as it stands, the scrolling of the inline-block element only affects the rendering of the content of that element. If the baseline moved when the user scrolled the element, other aligned elements would move, and consequently the whole page layout could be affected.

Comment: Looks interesting, but unfortunately, I can't grasp your idea and understand what exactly you mean. Please, could you give some example(s)?

Comment: overflow doesn't fix it completely.

Comment: @aimme)) I don't try to find a solution how to "fix" it. I try to understand what was the reason to change positioning behaviour of `inline-block` element when it is applied `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: overflow + size set will not show or mind overflowing content. margins on inline-block element increase size/room needed and will increase the line-height as well. test : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BoBeKo

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov just now posted my another answer briefing everything you need to know about this. hope it helps :) i am 100% sure thats what you are seeking.. enjoy :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1. What the reason to change baseline of inline-block element from baseline of its line box to bottom margin edge?**

The baseline of an 'inline-block' is changed to its bottom margin edge when its `overflow` property is set to `hidden` (full specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading)).

As for the reason for this decision, I think since the overflown part is hidden, user agents (browsers) may choose to render that overflown part and not display it, or choose to not render it at all. And **when the overflown part is not rendered, user agents have no way to tell the baseline of its last line box**, as it is not rendered, where it goes is not known.

If the baseline of 'inline-block' whose `overflow` is set to `hidden` is still kept as the baseline of its last line box, user agents are forced to render what is hidden to user, which **may hinder performance**, or at least, **put extra restrictions** on user agents. What's more, in such case, other inline texts in the same line box are aligned to such a baseline where texts around the overflow-hidden inline-box is hidden, which is **kind of stange and not intuitive**.

I made a simple demo emulating that inline-block with overflow hidden still has its baseline set to the baseline of its last line box.

[image: emultaing_imaginary_baseline_of_overflow_hidden_inline_block]

```js
var isOverflowHidden = false;
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('inline-box').style.overflow = isOverflowHidden ? '' : 'hidden';
  isOverflowHidden = !isOverflowHidden;
}
```

```css
html { background: white; }
#inline-box { display: inline-block; height: 18px; }
.overflown { color: white; }
```

```html
<p><button id="toggle">Toggle 'overflow: hidden;' on 'inline-block'</button></p>

<span>
  texts sit
  <span id="inline-box">
    texts in inline-block <br>
    <span class="overflown">
      line 2 <br>
      line 3
    </span>
  </span>
  on baseline
</span>
```

Besides, you may also compare this behavior with `display: none`. When that's set, `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` both equates to 0.

**2. How to calculate this shift?**

This part is much easier, since it's documented in the [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading) you gave in the question.

I'll start from the definition of 'line-height'.

> The height of the inline box encloses all glyphs and their half-leading on each side and is thus exactly 'line-height'.

That is, **line-height is composed of, from top to bottom, top half-leading + height(ascent) + depth(descent) + bottom half-leading**.

Height of each component can be calculated for a given font at a given size.

Basically, every font has font metrics that specify a characteristic height above the baseline and a depth below it.

Take 'Times New Roman' as an example, using *FontForge*, we see that it has `Em Size` as 2048, `HHead Ascent` as 1825, and `HHead Descent` as -443. That is, `1825 / 2048 = 89.1%` of font-size contributes to the ascent, and `443 / 2048 = 21.6%` contributes to the descent.

[image: FontForge]

There are also metrics starting with 'Typo', that category will be used if 'Really use Typo metrics' is checked, and the spec recommends this:

> Note. It is recommended that implementations that use OpenType or TrueType fonts use the metrics "sTypoAscender" and "sTypoDescender" from the font's OS/2 table for A and D (after scaling to the current element's font size). In the absence of these metrics, the "Ascent" and "Descent" metrics from the HHEA table should be used.

Line-height minus ascent and descent is the so-called leading.

> Half the leading is added above A(ascent) and the other half below D(descent).

Assuming a `font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 100px; line-height: 200px;`, we get

```
ascent = 100px * (1825 / 2048) = 89px
descent = 100px * (443 / 2048) = 22px
top half-leading = bottom half-leading = (200px - 89px - 22px) / 2 = 44.5px
```

So we see that this can be calculated. And this can also be measured on pages.

Here is another demo for you to fiddle with.

If you are asking for the shift of bottom half-leading, it's shown as space between green line and blue line in the code snippet.
If you are asking for the shift of descent and bottom half-leading, it's shown as space between red line and blue line in the code snippet.

```js
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle($('#examinee'))['font-family']
  , fontSize = +window.getComputedStyle($('#examinee'))['font-size'].replace('px', '')
  , containerLineHeight = +window.getComputedStyle($('#examinee'))['line-height'].replace('px', '')
  , textLineHeight = $('.target').offsetHeight
  , ascent = $('#examinee .baseline').offsetTop + $('#examinee .baseline').offsetHeight - $('#examinee .text-top').offsetTop
  , descent = $('#examinee .text-bottom').offsetTop - $('#examinee .baseline').offsetTop
  , topHalfLeading = $('#examinee .text-top').offsetTop
  , bottomHalfLeading = $('#examinee').offsetHeight - 2/* borders of the container */ - $('#examinee .text-bottom').offsetTop - $('#examinee .text-bottom').offsetHeight;

$('#font-family').innerText = fontFamily;
$('#font-size').innerText = fontSize + 'px';
$('#container-line-height').innerText = containerLineHeight + 'px';
$('#text-line-height').innerText = textLineHeight + 'px';
$('#ascent').innerText = ascent + 'px';
$('#descent').innerText = descent + 'px';
$('#top-half-leading').innerText = topHalfLeading + 'px';
$('#bottom-half-leading').innerText = bottomHalfLeading + 'px';
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 650px;
  
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span:not([class]) {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.baseline,
.text-bottom,
.text-top {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200%;
  margin: 0 -100%;
}

.baseline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: baseline;  /* the default */
}

.text-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.text-top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

#examinee {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Demonstrates that "overflow: hidden;" sets baseline of an inline-block element to its bottom margin.
</p>
<div>
  <span class="baseline"></span>
  <span class="text-top"></span>
  <span class="text-bottom"></span>
  &lt;div&gt;
  <span>
    &lt;span style=""&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
  </span>
  &lt;/div&gt;
</div>
<div>
  <span class="baseline"></span>
  <span class="text-top"></span>
  <span class="text-bottom"></span>
  &lt;div&gt;
  <span style="overflow: hidden;">
    &lt;span style="overflow: hidden;"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
  </span>
  &lt;/div&gt;
</div>

<p>
  Demonstrates the position of baseline, text-top and text-bottom. <br>
  Demonstrates how "line-height" affects box sizing.
</p>

<ul>
  <li>Blue lines: top and bottom borders of line boxes
  <li>Red lines: baseline of texts
  <li>Green lines: text-top or text-bottom of texts
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Between blue lines: the line-height
  <li>Between red line and green line: ascent or descent
</ul>

<div id="examinee">
  <span class="target">GgJjPpQqYy</span>
  <span class="baseline"></span>
  <span class="text-top"></span>
  <span class="text-bottom"></span>
</div>


Measured metrics:
<ul>
  <li>font-family: <span id="font-family"></span></li>
  <li>font-size: <span id="font-size"></span></li>
  <li>container line-height: <span id="container-line-height"></span></li>
  <li>text line-height: <span id="text-line-height"></span></li>
  <li>ascent: <span id="ascent"></span></li>
  <li>descent: <span id="descent"></span></li>
  <li>top half-leading: <span id="top-half-leading"></span></li>
  <li>bottom half-leading: <span id="bottom-half-leading"></span></li>
</ul>
```

[image: line-height measuring]

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer. but it might help to resolve this issue by removing the extra space in between `inline-block` elements.

```
<style>
.main_div {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.main_div span {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid green;
}

</style>
<div class="main_div">
    <span class="one">one</span>
    <span class="two">two</span>
    <span class="three">three</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea using `table` and `table-cell` displaying)

Answer (score 2):

@timur: First of all nice question.

I do not know whether it would answer your question but I would like to talk about some behaviour aspect of "inline-block" elements.

First of all, "inline-block" elements act according to its sibling elements and its content.

If there are two divs, one beside the other and both have display:inline-block; property:value then it would depend on the contents inside each div and would start displaying the content from the baseline which is the natural behaviour of "inline-block element".

Now, let me explain you "overflow" property behaviour.

By default, overflow property is "Visible" and its depended property is "overflow-wrap: normal;". Also it gets applied to only "block" level and "inline-block" elements because inline elements are those elements which wrap to the text and there are no white space inside the content to stop overflowing.

So the span in the example you have provided has to be "block" OR "inline-block" to apply overflow and vertical-align.

IF you look at this fiddle ---> http://jsfiddle.net/Lkyd1kr0/1/ where I have used "inline-block" for the second span element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one"><span>as</span></div><div class="two"><span>asd</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one,.two { 
width: 200px;
display: inline-block ;
```

}

```
.one { border: 2px solid #f00; }
.two { border: 2px solid #000; }

.one span { display: block; }

.two span { 
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now, just use Web developer tools and hover over the div.two and div.two > span and check the difference in height.

This is due to, as span is the content of the **div.two** who is **inline-block** and the rest of the space on the height of the div.two is secured for the rest of the content which is white space. This behavior you would generally see on "block" level and "inline-block" level elements.

Also, notice "transform-origin" of both "span" and "div.two" it would have  4px of difference on y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!)) Unfortunately, there is nothing new to me. The most interesting sentence is: `the rest of the space on the height of the div.two is secured for the rest of the content which is white space`. What does it mean "secured"? To secure what? What is "white space" in this context? Another moment confused me is `the span in the example has to be "block" OR "inline-block" to apply overflow and vertical-align`. Vertical-align can be applied to b, i-b, i etc. What did you mean?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: I meant block level and inline-block level doesn't wrap up the content and hence always left with the extra space at the content area for more text. 

Span is an inline element. And overflow property does not get applied to inline element. reference: [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Hence, we need to apply block level OR inline-block level property to span element.

Comment: I know that overflow is visible by default, I know that span is inline by default, I know that block and inline-block level elements doesn't wrap up the content by default. It's common things - there is nothing to speak) However question is still open: what the reason to move baseline from its line box to bottom margin edge for inline-block elements with overflow other than visible? Why it can't remain the position.

Answer (score 2):

**1. What the reason to change baseline of inline-block element from baseline of its line box to bottom margin edge?**

Its the default `line-height` or the normal line-height of its parent inherited to the inline-block element or the default value defined by the user agent  which is by the way W3C recommended `line-height:normal`.

**Reference here**

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height
says

> **normal**
>
> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
>   on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as
>   .
>
> > We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2. The
> >     computed value is 'normal'.

**So we know the default is `line-height:normal` and it inherits.** 
Now we know that inline-block adds the element the line-height and lets see what happens when overflow:hidden is set

[W3C - Overflow](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow) says

> - hidden
>
> The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.

overflow:hidden and display:inline-block creates space for the hanging characters like pgy. as it is block and inline, overflow preserves both space for the hanging characters that might come and line-height.

[image]

**2. How to calculate this shift?**

its browser specific and so we would need to refer browser specification

See here to know the value of 'normal'

[**mozilla**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

```
Initial value normal
Inherited yes
```

> **normal**
>       Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly 1.2, depending on the element's
>   font-family.

To understand the image, See the HTML CSS below

[image]

The Second div and Second Div Span has line-height:normal (which is 1.2 normally) because normal is inherited as its not defined.

The Third div and Third Div Span has line-height:40px which is defined, The value of the third div line-height was by default inherited to its inline child elements too.

[CSS/Properties/display](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display) says

- `inline-block`
     Causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the
  element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

As the term inline says it means the element is an inline element, and the block means its block. so together it means its a block element defined in the same line
here is the example proof that shows three situations
By default DIV is a block-Level element, and SPAN is an Inline Element. More information here [HTML Block and Inline Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

```
<style>
.first-div{
    border:#F00 1px solid;
}
.first-div span{
    /**by default span is an inline element.**/
    border:#093 1px solid;
}
.second-div{
    /** line-height not defined default line height will be used **/
    border:#F00 1px solid;
}
.second-div span{
    /** default line height inherited from the secod-div **/
    display:inline-block;
    border:#093 1px solid;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.third-div{
    border:#F00 1px solid;
    /**see line height. we change the default line height**/
    line-height:40px;
}
.third-div span{
    /**see line height. line height 40px set in the parent will be used**/
    display:inline-block;
    border:#093 1px solid;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<div class="first-div">
First Div
<span>First Span</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="second-div">
Second Div
<span>Second Span</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="third-div">
Third Div
<span>Third Span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for big explanation. I accept your answer, because you make an effort. Unfortunately I didn't get what I want. I think the problem in the questions itself. Regarding the first question: I wanted to understand why `inline-block` can't preserve baseline of its line box even if it has `overflow:hidden` (despite of W3C specification of course); I wanted to hear design decisions, not just it *must* be set to something, because W3C it mandate. The second one: I want to get a formula where we can paste `font-size` and `line-height` of parent element and get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

It's not will looks like answer, but I found a very interesting thing on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu) example.

If we take a lool to `#firstDiv` we can see some - margin in the bottom. But I think this margin taken from the height of horizontal scrollbar.

[image: Scrollbar]

I take a height of it, the height is near 14px;

Then take a height of top margin of out `inline-block` with `overflow: hidden` it's a 15px, and without `overflow: hidden` it's near 30px.

[image: 15px margin]
[image: 30px margin]

Is it a coincidence? I do not think. The same trick will be with larger height of `#container`.

P.S. This response does not purport to answer, I just could not put it all in a comment. I do not know how it's all connected, I just noticed this. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: The shift has nothing to do with horizontal scrollbar)) The value is based on `line-height` and `font-size` of a parent node. I found it has always 15% if `line-height` and `font-size` values are the same. But if they are different from each other it leads to more difficult calculations which I can't determine). Привет Украине!) Как там дела? Спокойно или все еще создают шум?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov "I found it has always 15% if line-height and font-size values are the same" - it's really very strange. But I think both of our guess are wrong:( Спасибо. Я с Киева, тут ничего такого нет. Не могу ничего сказать.