# css border of a span in div with line-height, the border is next to top

Tags: html, css

why the border of the span is next to top? if I delete the display of span, it works.
thank you.

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  line-height: 80px
}

.inner-span {
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="inner-span">123123</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Because line-height pushes the content down.

Comment: Just remove the line height and you are sorted. Due to line height it pushed the content down.

Comment: to be more precise, your span inherits the parent's line-height and as you restricted the span to 20px height (and the line height is 80px) the text looks like it is "outside" the box

Comment: in short : you are having overflow .. add overflow:auto to see what is happening

Comment: @VXp if i delete the span 'display:inline-block' ,it works. why ?

Comment: @HelloWorld because height doesn't apply to inline element

Comment: @Pete yeah,you are right.i set span line-height:20px, it works.thanks

Comment: @TemaniAfif I try it, it works.but how does it work？

Comment: you can check my answer, I tried to explaine it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other explained in the comments, the issue is that you have a fixed height of `20px` and you set a `line-height` that get inherited from the parent to `80px` so the line-box height is bigger thus you are having an overflow.

If you change the `line-height` of the inner span it will get fixed:

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  line-height: 80px
}

.inner-span {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="inner-span">123123</span>
</div>
```

Now why the border is positionned on the top?

It's because the default alignment is baseline and to define the baseline we consider the text.

> Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</sup>

If you change the `vertical-align` to be `bottom`, for example, you will see that the border will be on the bottom.

> Aligns the bottom of the element and its descendants with the bottom
>   of the entire line.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</sup>

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  line-height: 80px
}

.inner-span {
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="inner-span">123123</span>
</div>
```

If you add `overflow:auto` will clearly understand the overflow issue and you will also [change the baseline of the element to make it the bottom border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078950/why-baseline-of-inline-block-element-with-overflowhidden-is-set-to-its-bott):

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  line-height: 80px
}

.inner-span {
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="inner-span">123123</span>
</div>
```

If you remove the fixed height you will also notice that the height of the element will get defined by the `line-height` (the height of the line-box) and will logically be `80px`:

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  line-height: 80px
}

.inner-span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="inner-span">123123</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @HelloWorld I know it's very confusing to deal with those stuffs. By the way you may wait for Alohci or Boltclock and you will get more details ;) this is a very simplified explanation, there is a lot more behind all this