# Firefox inline-flex with overflow gains whitespace

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

When an element is set to `display: inline-flex` and has `overflow` set, Firefox is adding about 6px whitespace (similar to the 3px whitespace of normal inline elements).

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome/Safari/Edge**

[image]

Wondering if this is a bug with Firefox, or all other browsers?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/cloakedninjas/pen/XQMjvq

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-x: auto; /* comment out to remove whitespace */
}

li {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` will fix this (baseline issue, not sure why it only happens on Firefox)

Comment: Indeed it does - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting `vertical-align` property *fixes* this.  I guess the *issue* (the difference in behaviour with Firefox and other browsers) is this line in the spec<sup>1</sup>:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Take a look at the below demo in Firefox and chrome - *Firefox treats `inline-flex` also similar to the way it treats `inline-block` by using bottom margin as the baseline* <sup>2</sup>:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
}

li {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  inline
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Chrome*:

[image]

*Firefox*:

[image]

Another interesting thread:

[Why baseline of `inline-block` element with `overflow:hidden` is set to its bottom margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078950/why-baseline-of-inline-block-element-with-overflowhidden-is-set-to-its-bott/34183059)

---

#### References

<sup>1</sup> *Vertical Align*: [Vertical Align Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

<sup>2</sup> *CSS Working Group Editor Drafts*: [Spec doesn't say whether "overflow: [non-visible]" on flex/grid container triggers a different baseline (as it does for inline-block)](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2902)